# How do I expose my enterprise SQL Server to web services/mobile apps?

Tags: sql-server, web-services

My enterprise SQL Server deployment is currently local to our extranet. Now, I would like to expose some of this data to not only be consumed by web services and mobile apps, but allow those apps to actually create new records in the DB.

Also, one of my main hesitations is security. From a conceptual standpoint, what is involved in exposing data via a web service and ensuring that both the data and connection remain secure?

Are REST/OAuth or SOAP the only feasible options?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from the SQL side: We control the flow of data through stored procedures.

Web service/mobile app uses a sql login to access data in the database.  The sql login ONLY has access to execute stored procedures.  Those stored procedures use parameters to select/update/insert/delete only the records specified.

This prevents the app/web service from seeing any of the base tables or schema.

However, I can't speak on the security of the connection, that is an issue our developers and architects deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the input Dave. We have already implemented this internally.